# Hook into the vs2010 background compiler

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Title says everything. Is it possible to hook a  program between the vs2010 editor and the background compiler?

**Edit:**
I want to extend the c# syntax with new keywords. So I need to "send" the source code first to my own compiler that makes plain c# files out of the files with extended keywords...

Comment: Background compiler??  Do you mean IntelliSense parser?

Comment: Perhaps if you could explain what you wanted to accomplish, we could help more. There are *tons* of hooks exposed by VS, so there's probably one that you can use.

Comment: I want to extend the c# syntax with new keywords. So I need to "send" the source code first to my own compiler that makes plain c# files out of the files with extended keywords...

Comment: Matthias, what you are referring to is known as a macro

Comment: @Matt-nonuby: Can you explain?

Comment: "Yes". Please update your question to something answerable. You should not expect people to go hunting through the comments of other answers to gain rudimentary context on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is rather hackish, but you can call your parser via a pre-build event [as described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx). After the pre-build event finishes, the C# compiler should kick in.

I haven't tried this before, though, so please don't throw the tomatoes if it does not work :)

Regarding Intellisense, check out this possible duplicate question: [How to extend IntelliSense items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133887/how-to-extend-intellisense-items)

Comment: This is required anyway. But the problem is with the editor, that shows syntax errors when the source code is not valid over *plain* C#.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. This question is about the editor syntax highlightning. The other is about IntelliSense items.

Comment: Well, Google gives a good amount of results for such an endeavor. Here's one of them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253205/how-do-i-visual-studio-syntax-highlighting-extension